# login page error

Tags: php, authentication

I made a login page with php. when I use username and password as numbers there's no problem. but if I use a letter for username and password it will cause a problem and it gives this following error :

**Unknown column 'Column Name' in 'Where Clause'**

Any help will be appreciated

Update :

I use dreamweaver and I make the login page with these steps :

Insert->Data Objects->User Authentication->Log In User

Update 2 :

```
 <?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['user'];
  $password=$_POST['pass'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "ok.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_cn3, $cn3);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `user`=%s AND pass=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "-1"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $cn3) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: That has something to do with your SQL statement. Could you please post it?

Comment: Impossible to help you without you providing all the relevant information.

Comment: Show us the Query.. And a security tip. It is not safe to use the built-in login generator.. Write your own login query with PDO not `mysql_*`...

Comment: @MiroMarkarian see the Update 2

Comment: @aliboy38 `GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "-1")` ?? but why -1 ? that should be text too like the password field. change the -1 to text and check the result!

Answer (score 2):

Check your mysql statement that the databse name, table name, and column names are spelled correct.

I am sure that the `column name` of your db table, as the error says is misspelled. Check it. But to confirm it, show us the sql statement.

Try with;

```
$LoginRS__query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$loginUsername' AND pass = '$password'";
$LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: open your php file in notepad and look for some line containing sql , the mysql statement

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you need to encapsulate your variables in quotes within the query itself:

```
$var=3;
$sql="select someColumn from someTableName where userID=$var";
```

Will work but

```
$var=bobby;
$sql="select someColumn from someTableName where userID=$var";
```

Will not work. It needs to be:

```
$var=3;
$sql="select someColumn from someTableName where userID='$var'";
```

On that note though, if you are having a problem with yout SQL query, please post it and the relevant PHP code - otherwise we are forced to guess what is going on. In this case, the first part of your question *numbers okay* seems to imply quotes around variables while the *unknown column name* part implies that you have a typo.

Comment: @aliboy38 The update doesn't help much unfortunately. If you can show the table structure and the query, I have a funny feeling that it would be like shooting fish in a bucket though :)